# Attribute routing constraints with no parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to create attribute routing in MVC 5 application with one simple constraint:

```
public class UserAgentConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private string _requiredUserAgent;

    public UserAgentConstraint(string requiredUserAgent)
    {
        _requiredUserAgent = requiredUserAgent;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, 
        string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.UserAgent != null &&
               httpContext.Request.UserAgent.Contains(_requiredUserAgent);
    }
}
```

In MVC 4 i was able to register it in this way:

```
routes.MapRoute("ChromeRoute", "{*catchall}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
  new { customConstraint = new UserAgentConstraint("Chrome") });
```

How can i achieve same result using **only** attribute routing?
I know that i can register constraint in this way:

```
var constraintsResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
constraintsResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("UserAgent", typeof(UserAgentConstraint));
```

But how to add it to my route pattern? Something like this:

```
[Route("Home/Index:UserAgent(Chrome)")]
public ActionResult Index() {}
```

doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Attribute routing allows the following constraints to be applied and is used via this format {parameter:constraint} eg [Route("Index/{id:int}")]. So your attribute should be [Route("Home/{Index:UserAgent(Chrome)}")]

- {x:alpha}
- {x:bool}
- {x:datetime}
- {x:decimal}
- {x:double}
- {x:float}
- {x:guid}
- {x:int}
- {x:length()}
- {x:long}
- {x:max()}
- {x:maxlength()}
- {x:min()}
- {x:minlength()}
- {x:range()} {x:regex()}

Comment: Also, try calling this after adding the constraint

routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(constraintsResolver);

Comment: Unfortunatelyi dont have any parameter in Index action. I wany to pass customer constraint for the entire action and not only for selected parameter (which i dont have)

Comment: What exactly is trying to be done? Are you attempting to route elsewhere or prevent users from access given a specific user agent? Maybe an action filter would be better suited.

Comment: I want to route to specific action while user using browser other than "Google Chrome". For example i want to route user to "~/Home/Other" when he using IE, and route to "~/Home/Index" when he using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Review aspnetmvc source code,It can be helpful , try to review

RouteContraintAttribute , AreaAttribute and RouteAttribute

For example RouteConstraintAttribute:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/RouteConstraintAttribute.cs

I'm trying to figure out how to do that.